# Unable to start Nexus repository on CentOS 7 running on AWS

Tags: orientdb, nexus, sonatype, nexus3

Our Nexus repository ran out of space and now we cannot start the repository. Unfortunately, we do not have a backup of the repository that we can revert back to.

After we made some space on the disk 3.4. GB is free.
Now we are trying to fix the corrupt Orient databases namely config, and component. 
After we start the Orient DB console via

```
*sudo java -jar ./lib/support/nexus-orient-console.jar*
```

and try to connect to the config DB via

```
*CONNECT plocal:/mnt/sonatype-work/nexus3/db/config admin admin*
```

we are getting error com.orientechnologies.orient.core.exception.OStorageException: Cannot open local storage '/mnt/sonatype-work/nexus3/db/config' with mode=rw
    DB name="config"

> Connecting to database [plocal:/mnt/sonatype-work/nexus3/db/config]
>   with user 'admin'... 2018-11-24 02:23:00:977 WARNI {db=config} Storage
>   'config' was not closed properly. Will try to recover from write ahead
>   log... 2018-11-24 02:23:00:983 WARNI {db=config} Record
>   com.orientechnologies.orient.core.storage.impl.local.paginated.wal.OCheckpointEndRecord{lsn=LSN{segment=215,
>   position=52}} will be skipped during data restore$ANSI{green
>   {db=config}} Exception during storage data restore
>   java.lang.NullPointerException    at
>   com.orientechnologies.orient.core.storage.impl.local.paginated.wal.ODiskWriteAheadLog.cutTill(ODiskWriteAheadLog.java:919)
>     at
>
> $ANSI{green {db=config}} Error during storage close
>   java.lang.NullPointerException    at
>   com.orientechnologies.orient.core.storage.impl.local.paginated.wal.ODiskWriteAheadLog.cutTill(ODiskWriteAheadLog.java:919)
>     at
>
> Exception `475646D4` in storage
>   `plocal:/mnt/sonatype-work/nexus3/db/config`: 2.2.31 (build
>   285537d2767275f460df32c6a3be01bfff6a517c, branch 2.2.x)
>   com.orientechnologies.orient.core.exception.OStorageException: Cannot
>   open local storage '/mnt/sonatype-work/nexus3/db/config' with mode=rw
>     DB name="config"    at
>   com.orientechnologies.orient.core.storage.impl.local.OAbstractPaginatedStorage.open(OAbstractPaginatedStorage.java:323)

If we look at the processes running via htop we see multiple 
java -jar ./lib/support/nexus-orient-console.jar running.

Not sure if that is causing a problem connecting to the config db.

Any ideas or recommendations to fix the issue?

Answer (score 2):

Just wanted to share that this issue appears to have been resolved with a conversation on this mailing list: https://groups.google.com/a/glists.sonatype.com/forum/?utm_medium=email&utm_source=footer#!msg/nexus-users/64W_y9fDGzQ/o0FKRgiDAwAJ